# MongoDB into a Celery Task - Flask Application

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, celery

I'm trying to use Celery on my Flask application.
I'm defining a *task* in a file `insight_tasks.py`.
In that file is defined a function:

```
@celery_app.task
def save_insights_task()
```

That function do some stuff and, here comes the error, I'm trying to save data into MongoDB and the console throws me:
**MongoEngineConnectionError('You have not defined a default connection',)**
So I think it's because MongoEngine has not been initialized, and here is my question:

How should I use *MongoDB* inside a Celery Task?, because when using MongoDB on my routes (flask app) It's working as expected.

Celery does not share the db instance?

#### Files:

**__init__.py (Celery intialization)**

```
celery_app = Celery('insights',
                broker=config.CELERY_LOCATIONS_BROKER_URL,
                backend=config.CELERY_LOCATIONS_RESULT_BACKEND,
                include=['app.insight_tasks']
                )
```

**insight_tasks.py**

```
from app.google import google_service
from app.models import LocationStats
from . import celery_app
from firebase_admin import db as firebase_db
import arrow


@celery_app.task
def save_insight_task(account_location, uid, gid, locations_obj, aggregation):

    try:
        insights, reviews = google_service.store_location_resources(
            gid, uid,
            start_datetime, end_datetime,
            account_location, aggregation
        )
    except StandardError as err:
        from pprint import pprint
        import traceback
        pprint(err)
        pprint(traceback.print_exc())

    path = 'saved_locations/{}/accounts/{}'.format(gid, account_location)
    location = [loc for loc in locations_obj if loc['name'] == 'accounts/' + account_location]
    if len(location) > 0:
        firebase_db.reference(path).update(location[0])
```

Here `google_service.store_location_resources()` is the function that saves thew data into MongoDB. this function is used on another side, by the **routes** of my app, so it works as expected, except on the *Celery task*

**---------**

The Celery task is called into a *POST* request

**accounts/routes.py**

```
@account.route('/save/queue', methods=['POST'])
def save_all_locations():
    data = request.data
    dataDict = json.loads(data)
    uid = request.headers.get('uid', None)
    gid = request.headers.get('gid', None)

    account_locations = dataDict['locations']
    locations_obj = dataDict['locations_obj']
    for path in account_locations:
        save_insight_task.delay(account_location=path, uid=uid, gid=gid, locations_obj=locations_obj, aggregate='SOME_TEXT')
```

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to connect to the database inside the task. The reason is because child processes (created by Celery) must have their own instance of mongo client.

More details [here : Using PyMongo with Multiprocessing](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/faq.html#using-pymongo-with-multiprocessing)

For example define a **utils.py** :

```
from pymodm import connect
def mongo_connect():
    return connect("mongodb://{0}:{1}/{2}".format(MONGODB['host'],
                                    MONGODB['port'],
                                    MONGODB['db_name']),
                                    alias=MONGODB['db_name'])
```

Then in **insight_tasks.py**

```
from utils import mongo_connect
@celery_app.task
def save_insight_task(account_location, uid, gid, locations_obj, aggregation):
    # connect to mongodb
    mongo_connect()
    # do your db operations
    try:
        insights, reviews = google_service.store_location_resources(
            gid, uid,
            start_datetime, end_datetime,
            account_location, aggregation
        )
    except StandardError as err:
        from pprint import pprint
        import traceback

        pprint(err)
        pprint(traceback.print_exc())

    path = 'saved_locations/{}/accounts/{}'.format(gid, account_location)
    location = [loc for loc in locations_obj if loc['name'] == 'accounts/' + account_location]
    if len(location) > 0:
        firebase_db.reference(path).update(location[0])
```

Note that I use `pymodm` package instead of `mongoengine` package as ODM for mongo.